# Access xml element attribute with <!..>

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to write a small program to read data from an XML file and write it to CSV. I usually work with element tree.

The XML files have their origin in an application for mobile phones and always look like this:

```
<waypoint><name><![CDATA[POI 2017-07-03 09:37:11nass]]></name> 
<coord lat="47.220430" lon="8.951071"/></waypoint>
```

I do not have any problem to access the coord-root and its content (longitude and latitude). But how can I access the information of the name: `[CDATA[POI 2017-07-03 09:37:11nass]]`?

My code looks like this so far:

```
for poi in POIS:
    tree = etree.parse(rootwayp + poi)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        for childchild in child:
            print(childchild.tag, ':', childchild.attrib)
```

I think I need to implement another reading method for the name-content, as the bracket does not include the information there. I have tried to access the information as a subchild of name, which does not work (maybe because of the ! in the brackets?) What exactly does the ! in `<!...>` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<![CDATA[...]]>` is a special 
[marked section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455069/6655211)

You can use the following selectors to extract the details you need :

```
root = tree.getroot()

print(root.find('name').text)
print(root.find('coord').attrib.get('lat','n/a'))
print(root.find('coord').attrib.get('lon','n/a'))

# Output
POI 2017-07-03 09:37:11nass
47.220430
8.951071
```

With lxml, you can extract the whole CDATA section, [here is some doc about.](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata)